# fast click jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I am using fastClick, a jquery plugin that I installed a few years ago, and when I looked it up, it explained that it solves mobile browser's 300ms delay. However, is this delay still an issue that needs to be resolved in 2023? If it is unnecessary, I would like to remove the library. Rather, I would like to know if there are any harmful effects.

Comment: Did you check the source?  They say the plugin hasn't been necessary since 2015.  https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

Comment: The lastest vanilla javascript capabilities has pretty much made jquery obsolete in most aspects. See [this information](https://github.com/camsong/You-Dont-Need-jQuery) that has various examples using vanilla javascript equivalents to jquery.

Comment: @PaulT. it's not really "vanilla JavaScript" because browser APIs are not part of the programming language. And there are still things that jQuery does that are useful, like managing event handling delegation, implicit iteration, and some extended selector syntax. (and more)

Comment: @Pointy ... hey, I agree on the jQuery things, as the link says that you _might_ not need jQuery. Anyway, in our shop, we have already been shifting away from jQuery, as most things did not need it anyway for the basic javascript handling that simply replaces the same functionality, and eliminates the need for yet-another 3rd party library.

Comment: @PaulT. yea I confess that a few years of "vanilla JavaScript" talk have driven me slightly crazy :) Plus I'm still a jQuery fan, for old times' sake if nothing else.